# View with minHeight in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `NestedScrollView`. The `ConstraintLayout` contains a bunch of views but the last `View` can have a dynamic height to fill up the bottom space if there is any but it also needs to be a minimum height if there is not enough space.

For arguments sake, here is an example.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="1500dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
 
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

As you can see I have put the `ConstraintLayout` version in but it doesn't work. Obviously the values are ridiculously large but this is just for testing.

If I don't set `fillViewport="true"` on the `NestedScrollView` then `ConstraintLayout` has a height of 0. When I do set the `fillViewport`, the `ConstraintLayout` does not scroll but just fills the screen.

How can I set the View so that it expands to the bottom of the `ConstraintLayout` which should be as big as the Viewport but if my View is not of the `minHeight` then we allow scrolling?

I am using version `1.0.2` of the `ConstraintLayout` library.

What I expect to see is the being all the way to the bottom of the parent but if that size is less than `1500dp` then the view scrolls.

I have entered 1500dp like so `android:layout_height="1500dp"` and the view scrolls accordingly.

*UPDATE 1*

Seems to be once I put the layout within a `FragmentViewPager`. The `app:layout_constraintHeight_min` property isn't respected and it only matches the height of the viewport.

I also tried taking the `NestedScrollView` out of the fragment and putting the `ViewPager` inside it but again didn't work.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add this attribute to the view you'd like to have stretch:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
```

I made a tiny app to demonstrate. No java logic to speak of, but here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#caf">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/two"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:background="#eee"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/three"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:background="#ddd"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The bottom view stretches to fill the viewport when it is smaller than the remaining available space, and scrolling is impossible:

[image]

The bottom view maintains a fixed height when it is larger than the remaining available space, which makes scrolling possible:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I used your answer to debug why the contraint layout wasn't working and found that other views with different constraints didn't play nicely with it. I changed the way these other views were constrained and it started working. My next problem is why it's not working when I put it in my ViewPager...

Comment: Ok it seems to be the `ViewPager` thats causing the issue

Answer (score 4):

I am using `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2` and this works for me:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="1500dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first thing is we have to specify the fixed height to each text view or used wrap content as another option.Secondary inside constraint layout the property **app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"** helps the last view to get the remaining complete space left and if no space left then automatically synced to scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#caf"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/two"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#eee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/three"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/one" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#eee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/four"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            anroid:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#eee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/five"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/three" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello world"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/three" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```